# My recursive maze solver does not recognize start position correctly

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I'm trying to write the code for a recursive maze solver. This is what I have so far:

```
const int NROWS = 5;
const int MCOLS = 12;

// Symbols:
// ' ' = open
// 'X' = blocked
// 'S' = start
// 'E' = goal
// '.' = path
// '+' = bad path

char maze[NROWS][MCOLS+1] = {
    {"S XXXXXXXXXX"},
    {"X  X   XX  X"},
    {"XX   XX X XX"},
    {"XX X       X"},
    {"XXXXXXXXXEXX"},
    };


void display_maze(void);
bool find_path(int x, int y);


int main()
{
    display_maze();

    if ( find_path(0, 0) == true )
        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("Failed\n");

    display_maze();

    return 0;
}



void display_maze()
{
    int i;

    printf("MAZE:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < NROWS; i++ )
    printf("%.*s\n", MCOLS, maze[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return;
}


bool find_path(int x, int y)
{
    // If x,y is outside maze, return false.
    if ( x < 0 || x > MCOLS - 1 || y < 0 || y > NROWS - 1 ) return false;

    // If x,y is the goal, return true.
    if ( maze[y][x] == 'E' ) return true;

    // If x,y is not open, return false.
    if ( maze[y][x] != ' ' && maze[y][x] != 'S' ) return false;

    // Mark x,y part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '.';

    // If find_path North of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x, y - 1) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path East of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x + 1, y) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path South of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x, y + 1) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path West of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x - 1, y) == true ) return true;

    // Unmark x,y as part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '+';

    return false;
}
```

For this iteration of the maze, it works fine. The output prints "Success" and shows the pathway from 'S' to 'E'.

However, should I move the position of 'S' like so:

```
XXXXXXSXXXXX
X  X   XX  X
XXX  XX X XX
XX X       X
XXXXX XXXEXX
```

The output prints "Failed". I have a feeling that from the recursion code I've written, my maze automatically fails if it does not find ' ' or 'S' right away. I'm just not sure how to implement the code to keep searching for the 'S' though.

Another question- As you can see, I implemented a sample maze within my .cpp file. However, my end goal is to stream a maze from a .txt file. Each maze will thus have different dimensions. Would it make more sense for me to use a vector then rather than a char array?

Comment: You need to actually *search* for the starting position first, and make the first call with that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the maze,

```
XXXXXXSXXXXX
X  X   XX  X
XXX  XX X XX
XX X       X
XXXXX XXXEXX
```

when you are calling find_path() with parameter (0,0) which contains **X** in that position. So

```
 if ( maze[y][x] != ' ' && maze[y][x] != 'S' ) return false;
```

is executed in *find_path()* which returns false. So output is *Failed*.

You must find out the position of 'S' and then call find_path() with those parameters.

***For your second question:***

You can use vector or STL string too. You can use character type array too, if you know the max number of row given in the ***.txt*** file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for the .txt file, I won't know in advance the number of rows and columns the maze will have. Would you recommend using a vector or string?

Comment: Both vector and string need to know max number of column given in the file(If you use 2D). But if you use 1D string or vector, then no need to know max number of row or column. But then handling your maze will be complex through coding.

Comment: Understood. I'll see if I can have that clarified with my professor. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I'm saying again, it is possible to represent 2D Maze, through 1D String or vector(your maze is a rectangle, so less complex, but still you need more code to handle 2D maze in 1D string or vector). If maze can be in any shape, then it will be more complex to present 2D maze in 1D string or vector.

Comment: I know for sure that all mazes implemented will  be rectangular, but can you explain how I can implement it as a 1D string or vector?

Answer (score 1):

well，I changed a little bit base on your code

```
enum FromDirection{
    Origin,
    North_dir,
    East_dir,
    South_dir,
    West_dir,
 }

int main()
{
    display_maze();
    int find_result = find_path(0, 0, Origin);
    if ( find_result == true )
        printf("Success!\n");
    else
        printf("Failed\n");

    display_maze();
    return 0;
}

bool find_path(int x, int y, int ifrom_dir)
{
    static bool find_enterence = false;
    // If x,y is outside maze, return false.
    if ( x < 0 || x > MCOLS - 1 || y < 0 || y > NROWS - 1 ) return false;

    // If x,y is the goal, return true.
    if ( maze[y][x] == 'E' ) return true;

    // If x,y is not open, return false.
    if ( maze[y][x] != ' ' && maze[y][x] != 'S' ) {
        if( find_enterence){
            return false;
        }
        // check last position in case of backtracking
        if (ifrom_dir != North_dir && find_path(x, y - 1, South_dir)){
            return true;
        }
        if(ifrom_dir != East_dir && find_path(x + 1, y, West_dir)){
            return true;
        }
        if(ifrom_dir != South_dir && find_path(x, y+ 1, North_dir)){
            return true;
        }
        if (ifrom_dir != West_dir && find_path(x - 1, y, East_dir)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Mark x,y part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '.';
    find_enterence = true;
    // If find_path North of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( ifrom_dir != North_dir && find_path(x, y - 1, South_dir) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path East of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( ifrom_dir != East_dir && find_path(x + 1, y, West_dir) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path South of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( ifrom_dir != South_dir && find_path(x, y + 1, North_dir) == true ) return true;

    // If find_path West of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( ifrom_dir != West_dir && find_path(x - 1, y, East_dir) == true ) return true;

    // Unmark x,y as part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '+';

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I see that you added a bool within the recursion function that would keep the program running if it doesn't find 'S' right away. However, can you explain how find_entrance switches to true? From what it seems, it would switch to true either when it finds ' ' or 'S'.

Comment: yes, once it finds out the first ' ' or 'S',  I switch the bool variable to true